# Hanging balance with pivot not working, parts falling through each other

Tags: animation, physics

This has got to be simple, I'm doing something wrong and overlooking the obvious. I have a beam with a pivot, a support post, and a weight at the end (also on a pivot). The pivots are cylinders, the beam is a cube, the support post is a cube, and the weight is a cube. The cubes have been 'boolean-ed' to make the necessary space for movement. The problem is, everything falls apart and through each other. I have looked at other questions here on SE concerning the 'fall-through' problem, but they all deal with active and passive settings. As far as I can tell, everything is set correctly. They bounce off each other and the floor after falling apart. There's something about the holes in the support and weight that are not interacting with the pivot pins. What am I missing?

Link to the file: [image]

[image: animated example of the problem]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with putting a gear on a spindle.  It kept shooting off into space.  The problem was that in the rigid body constraint, the "Sensitivity" collision margin defaults to 0.04, and for me, I had to lower it to 0.001.

Comment: Increasing the Sensitivity got me much better results. However, I also found I had to increase the Steps Per Second under Rigid Body World in the Scene panel. But what made it all work in the first place was changing the Shape under Rigid Body Collisions to Mesh instead of the default Convex Hull. That got things interacting with each other. Then it was a matter of tweaking the other parameters to make it look right. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the Shape under Rigid Body Collisions was set to the default of Convex Hull. Changing it to Mesh made things work as expected, with the addition of increasing the Sensitivity. Increasing Steps Per Second in the Rigid Body World settings improved the interaction as well.

[image: image showing where to increase sensitivity and change shape to mesh]